# Composite primary key in hibernate cannot be create

Tags: hibernate, composite-key

I am trying to create these situation: 
User --------> User's rate about Author <------------ Author

So I got class:

```
public class User implements UserDetails {

        @Id
    private String username;
        (...)
        @OneToMany(targetEntity=RateAth.class, mappedBy="user", cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
        List<RateAth> authorRates

public class Author {

        @Id
    private int id;
    (...)
        @OneToMany(targetEntity=RateAth.class, mappedBy="author", cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<RateAth> authorRates;
```

And here is my RateAth class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="users_authors_rate")
public class RateAth {
    @Id
    private PK primaryKey;
    private Integer rate;
    private Date date;
    private String username;

    @Id
    public PK getPrimaryKey() {
        return primaryKey;
    }
    public void setPrimaryKey(PK primaryKey) {
        this.primaryKey = primaryKey;
    }
    public Integer getRate() {
        return rate;
    }
    public void setRate(Integer rate) {
        this.rate = rate;
    }
    public Date getDate() {
        return date;
    }
    public void setDate(Date date) {
        this.date = date;
    }
    public User getUser() {
        return primaryKey.getUser();
    }
    public void setUser(User user) {
        this.primaryKey.setUser(user);
    }

    public Author getAuthor() {
        return primaryKey.getAuthor();
    }
    public void setAuthor(Author author) {
        this.primaryKey.setAuthor(author);
    }

    }
@Embeddable 
class PK implements Serializable{
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="username")
    private User user;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="author_id")
    private Author author;

    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }
    public void setUser(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    public Author getAuthor() {
        return author;
    }
    public void setAuthor(Author author) {
        this.author = author;
    }


}
```

> ... 49 more Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not
>   determine type for: beans.Author, at table: users_authors_rate, for
>   columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(author)]   at
>   org.hibernate.mapping.SimpleValue.getType(SimpleValue.java:292)   at
>   org.hibernate.mapping.SimpleValue.isValid(SimpleValue.java:276)   at
>   org.hibernate.mapping.Property.isValid(Property.java:207)     at
>   org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.validate(PersistentClass.java:458)
>     at org.hibernate.mapping.RootClass.validate(RootClass.java:215)     at
>   org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.validate(Configuration.java:1135)     at
>   org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1320)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.buildSessionFactory(AnnotationConfiguration.java:867)
>     at
>   org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean.newSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:860)
>     at
>   org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:779)
>     at
>   org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.AbstractSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractSessionFactoryBean.java:211)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1477)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1417)
>     ... 56 more

Answer (score 0):

Read http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#d0e4865.

The `@Id` annotation must be placed on the field or on the getter, but not both.
It must be replaced by `@EmbeddedId` since it's an embedded object and not a single column field.

And I would make the class immutable and remove the `setAuthor` and `setUser` methods from the entity, since you can't change the primary key of an entity.